# JS - Sum List of Array (Sum Names in Text Field)

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, button, input

I am trying to make a button that when clicked prints in a text filed input (id="textName") a random name from an Array of names. No problem so far!

After that, all the names need to sum to each other in another texfield (id="addName") and update every click adding the new name. Like having a list of names separated by a coma fiat, bmw, masaserati, ferrari).

this is my code so far.

```
<input type="button" id="randomName" value="name" style="position:relative; top:200px; left:50px;" />


<input  type="text" id="textName" value="" style="position:relative; top:200px; left:100px; width:200px;" />

<input  type="text" id="addName" value="" style="position:relative; top:300px; left:0px; width:80%;" />



<script >



var Names = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Fiat", "Ferrari", "Maserati", "Audi"];


document.getElementById('randomName').onclick = function() {
  //add code here
  var NumberRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);
  var allNames = Names[NumberRandom];

  $('#textName').val(allNames);

  console.log(NumberRandom);


  for(var i=0; i<NumberRandom; i++){

                var total = Names[NumberRandom] += 1 ;

                    console.log(total);

                    $('#addName').val(total);

                        return;
                    }

                }

</script>
```

here the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/m2Upg/

Any Idea how to have sum the names every click separated by coma in the addName input?

Comment: What do you mean by "names need to sum to each other"? Summing is usually done with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKEaL/)

```
var Names = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Fiat", "Ferrari", "Maserati", "Audi"];


document.getElementById('randomName').onclick = function() {
  //add code here
  var NumberRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * Names.length));
  var allNames = Names[NumberRandom];

  $('#textName').val(allNames);

  console.log(NumberRandom);

    var curVal = $("#addName").val()
    if (curVal.length > 0) {
        curVal += ','
    }
    curVal += allNames
    $("#addName").val(curVal)

}
```

Note the change in the generation of the random number (line 6) and the `curVal` change at the bottom (line 13-18).

Comment: Please place the answer here (linking is okay). If the link dies, there is no future reference.

Comment: is there a way to count the names? I am trying using "curVal.length" but instead it adds the number of letters together

Comment: is there a way to count the names? I am trying using "curVal.length" but instead it adds the number of letters together

Comment: You should probably use an array instead of a string if you want to count the names.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Upg/1/)***

```
var Names = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Fiat", "Ferrari", "Maserati", "Audi"];


document.getElementById('randomName').onclick = function () {
//add code here
var NumberRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var allNames = Names[NumberRandom];

$('#textName').val(allNames);

console.log(NumberRandom);


for (var i = 0; i < NumberRandom; i++) {

    var total = Names[NumberRandom] += 1;
    var prev = $('#addName').val();
    console.log(prev);
    if (prev != '') {
        prev += ',' + total;
    }else{
        prev = total;
    } 

    $('#addName').val(prev);

    return;
}

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing single not equals in javascript (`!=`). Also, for checking non-empty string, do `string.length > 0`